# How to display a binded table(ArrayList of Bean) in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I want to display something like this on my jsp page..
It is a table where each row correspond to a bean. So basically the table represents arraylist of bean.

```
<td class="varcar"><form:input  path="trackRecordEntries[index].installmentNo"/></td>
```

Problem is how can i get the current index of the arraylist.  If i do something like this

```
<td class="varcar"><form:input  path="trackRecordEntries[0].installmentNo"/></td>
```

i get 5 rows but all binded to the first object in arraylist

Any Solution ??

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using JSTL's foreach loop? http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/10/jstl-foreach-tag-example-in-jsp-looping.html

EDIT
Nice links:
[JSTL print array list values in ul - li html tag. Right Algorithm.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6873459/jstl-print-array-list-values-in-ul-li-html-tag-right-algorithm)
[JSTL Printing arrayList elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383449/jstl-printing-arraylist-elements)